# Link to article detail from article list using the same state/fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to display one articles content separately when clicking ones title with link in the list of all articles. I have the code below, and it works, but only if coming from the list, not if I type in the whole url to the spesific article.

**ArticleList.js**

```
<div key={article.id}>
    <Link to={{
        pathname: `/${article.slug}`,
        state: {article},
        }}>{article.headline}</Link>

    <p>{article.summary}</p>
</div>
```

**ArticleDetail.js**

```
class ArticleDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="current-article">
        <h2>{this.props.location.state.article.headline}</h2>
        <p>{this.props.location.state.article.content}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/:slug" component={ArticleDetail}/>
            // The ArticleList component is imported in "App" with <ArticleList />
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Using react-router. I'm sure this is not the proper way of achieving this, but after searching for hours I just can't believe such a simple thing have to be so complicated. Could someone please point me in the right direction, to a proper solution that (preferably) don't require 50 lines of code and 3 external libraries?

Thanks for your time and help.

### Edit

This is obviously not what I'm after, but would perhaps be nice in redirects. Do I have to fetch from the API again in the ArticleDetail component? How does this component get ${article.slug} from the link pathname in the ArticleList component?

Comment: Try to log this.props.location.state when you come from url. I think that is is undefined or however "article" object is undefined.

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo Yes, the state is undefined unless coming from the list. "TypeError: this.props.location.state is undefined". Just want to show the content of an article in it's own view, and where this content resides within the list components state.

Comment: (or not if this is not the proper way of achieving this)

Comment: Your location.state is obviously undefined! Who pass it to your components? In the  list case is obviously the state you pass to in Link.to !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to use the slug, fetch the article information and then render the data.

In your ArticleDetail component read the slug using this.props.location or this.props.match.param (or just log your this.props to understand where you can get route param). After you know what "slug" is you can fetch article data and display it.

This way you can always see correct data in your ArticleDetails page, both when use click on listItem and when user types the url.

The error now is that when you access the page typing the url you don't have the state in your props.location because no one is passing it. In your list you have the state and so you can correctly see the ArticleDetail:

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: `/${article.slug}`,
    state: {article}, // <---
    }}>{article.headline}</Link>
```

The state prop (arrow comment) will be send to the "/:slug" page only when you click on Link element.

Comment: Ok, yes I understand what you were trying to say now. I did it this way and now it works. Did a new fetch and passed the url the slug param with "${this.props.match.params.slug}" in ArticleDetail. Much better, thanks.